# TTTAttributedLabel : issue detecting links.

Tags: tttattributedlabel

I've been having some issues while using TTTAttributedLabel. Sometimes a given URL doesn't get coloured as a link nor does it react to touch. However, this is solved by scrolling down and up, so by making the Cell view re-draw. I've looking at the issues in the project's github, but the ones that seemed related were already closed.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the fix was to move the 
    .enabledTextCheckingTypes = NSTextCheckingTypeLink;
to the **awakeFromNib** method the custom UITableViewCell.