# TTTAttributedLabel Link detecting not work in iOS8 with swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, ios8, tttattributedlabel

I want to use TTTAttributedLabel to detect the link of the text in the Label of UITableViewCell, but it doesn't work. I'm using swift with iOS8. below is UITableViewCell code:

```
class StoryTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, TTTAttributedLabelDelegate {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

        // Link properties
        let textLabel = self.descriptionLabel
        let linkColor = UIColor(red: 0.203, green: 0.329, blue: 0.835, alpha: 1)
        let linkActiveColor = UIColor.blackColor()

        if (textLabel is TTTAttributedLabel) {
            var label = textLabel as TTTAttributedLabel
            label.linkAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : linkColor]
            label.activeLinkAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : linkActiveColor]        
            label.enabledTextCheckingTypes = NSTextCheckingType.Link.toRaw()

            label.delegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out : http://stackoverflow.com/a/22395136/1106035

Comment: @Prince it's not work

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you have not configured your `custom cell` **correctly**.

**First** at your customCell declare and connect your `IBOutlet`-s. Select your textLabel and add its class to `TTTAttributedLabel`. Your custom cell should look like this:

```
class StoryTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var textLabel: TTTAttributedLabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

**Second** you need to add the `TTTAttributedLabelDelegate` at the class where you are using the tableView datasource and delegate.

**Then** under `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
var cell: StoryTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("yourCellIdentifier") as StoryTableViewCell

let linkColor = UIColor(red: 0.203, green: 0.329, blue: 0.835, alpha: 1)
let linkActiveColor = UIColor.blackColor()

cell.textLabel.delegate = self

cell.textLabel.linkAttributes = [kCTForegroundColorAttributeName : linkColor]
cell.textLabel.activeLinkAttributes = [kCTForegroundColorAttributeName : linkActiveColor]        
cell.textLabel.enabledTextCheckingTypes = NSTextCheckingType.Link.rawValue
```

Then if you have methods that need to be executed from `TTTAttributedLabelDelegate` add them and do your calculations.

Hope it helps

Comment: I followed your answer but I am not being able to make it work. Any idea on how to debug it? The text is there but no link is being found.

Comment: UPDATE 1: I started debugging by adding the delegate functions attributedLabel didSelectLinkWithURL and didLongPressLinkWithURL. The former was not working but the latter is.

UPDATE 2: The didSelectLinkWithURL was not being called because I had a tapper in the view that was with tapper.cancelsTouchesInView = true. When I set it to false, the click started to work.

Comment: It appears that NSForegroundColorAttributeName is not working on iOS8. If that happens, just use kCTForegroundColorAttributeName instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you've set TTTAttributedLabel as the class of your UILabel, within a nib or the storyboard, make sure **User Interaction Enabled** is set to true, as be default a UILabel will have user interaction disabled.

Answer (score 0):

```
    let linkColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    let linkActiveColor = UIColor.greenColor()

    textLabel.delegate = self

    textLabel.linkAttributes = [kCTForegroundColorAttributeName : linkColor.CGColor,kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName : NSNumber(bool: true)]
    textLabel.activeLinkAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : linkActiveColor]
    textLabel.enabledTextCheckingTypes = NSTextCheckingType.Link.rawValue
```

Comment: hi kamlesh i am facing clicking problem in truncation token in tttattributedlabel.Do you have an idea of that?

Answer (score 0):

swift 4.2
label.enabledTextCheckingTypes = NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue | NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.phoneNumber.rawValue

Answer (score 0):

Nothing works for me finally i put below code in TTTAttributedLabel.m in commonInit() method

```
    self.enabledTextCheckingTypes = NSTextCheckingTypeLink;
```